# Is the function order guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, function

```
let x = 0;
function a() {
    console.log("called a()");
    for (let i=0; i<123456789; ++i) {
        x += Math.sqrt(2);
    }
    console.log("x = "+x);
}
function b() {
    x = undefined;
    console.log("called b()");
}
setTimeout(b, 20);
a();
```

output:

```
called a()
x = 174594265.7306214
called b()
```

`b` should have been called sooner, but it waited until the function `a` completed.

I know js uses only one thread, but the processor could have switched between executing `a` and `b` during `a`'s execution. Does the processor always execute only one function at a time (if there is no await inside)? In nodejs and in website javascript?

**EDIT:**
Here is an await example:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
let x = 0;
async function a() {
    console.log("called a()");
    await sleep(1000);
    for (let i=0; i<123456789; ++i) {
        x += Math.sqrt(2);
    }
    console.log("x = "+x);
}
function b() {
    x = undefined;
    console.log("called b()");
}
setTimeout(b, 20);
a();
```

output:

```
called a()
called b()
x = NaN
```

notice how x becomes NaN, since `b` is executed during `a`

Comment: `but the processor could have switched between executing a and b during a's execution.` No it couldn't. JavaScript runs (in a) task loop. One task at a time.

Comment: with `setTimeout` you give *the minimum* time to wait. The thread still has to be idle to run your task, so if something is already running, the execution of `b` would be delayed further.

Comment: RE the edit - still only a single function gets executed at once. Async functions can be paused/unpaused and will continue from where they left off. In the mean time other functions can run. If something modifies *the same state the async function works with*, then the code just continues using that new state.

Comment: `b is executed during a` - to be more specific, `b` is executed before the `await` in `a` returns. Javascript can **wait** in parallel but cannot execute code in parallel since it is singlethreaded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> b should have been called sooner, but it waited until the function a
> completed.

No. `b` should be called *after* your synchronous code has executed because that's when a function passed to `setTimeout` is called.

Callback function of `setTimeout` is scheduled to run after the delay you specify as a second argument to `setTimeout`. This delay is the minimum amount of time it will take to run the callback function scheduled using `setTimeout`.

Once the timer expires, that callback function is put in a task queue and from there it is pushed to the call stack BUT it is only pushed once the call stack is empty.

In your case, call stack will be empty when your script has finished its execution.

> I know js uses only one thread, but the processor could have switched
> between executing a and b during a's execution

That's not possible with only 1 thread. In Javascript, only one thing executes at a given time, unless you use another [thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

> Does the processor always execute only one function at a time (if
> there is no await inside)

Yes. Even with `await`, function is paused until the promise is settled. Once the promise settles, that function continues execution and at that time, nothing else executes.

#### Edit

> notice how x becomes NaN, since b is executed during a

No, there is no interference here. Function `a` is executed synchronously until the following statement

```
await sleep(1000);
```

While the function `a` is paused, waiting for the promise returned by `sleep(...)` to settle, during this time, function `b` is executed because its timer has expired and the call stack is empty.

Since both functions assign to same variable `x`, value of `x` is `NaN` because its value before function `a` resumes is `undefined` and performing addition on `undefined` leads to `NaN`.